# Relatively positioned div not pushing footer down

Tags: css

The page is accessible at http://tattech.ru/uslugi/novaya-stranitsa.php

The contact form and banner are wrapped inside `cf-banner` class. It's positioned relatively. The problem is it's not pushing my footer down.

Positioning footer absolutely is not an option because it doesn't work well with long content. What can be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Include the relevant code in the question, preferably in a runnable code snippet.

Comment: Putting `clear:both` before footer solved the issue.

Comment: @kulan so upvote the correct answer, I saw a correct answer here

Comment: @Desperado I have. Someone must downvoted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `.cf-banner` is floating.
Clear the float by declaring `clear: both` on the `footer` element.

**CSS**

```
footer {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
```